# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') when using MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

Why do I keep encountering this error when using the Grid of MUI in my react component
[image]

this is the whole code of the component

```
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={6} md={8}>
          hasdsadsa
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

but once I comment the Grid Tag below the program runs fine

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Comment: Is there a `useTheme.js` file ?

Comment: nope. I don't have any useTheme files and calls in my project

Comment: maybe we should check the same kind of issues reported in their github issues

Comment: Basically the issue is that `React` is undefined for some reason. View [source](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-private-theming/src/useTheme/useTheme.js#L5). Is `react` actually installed? Could you try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-kalam-bxq3el?file=/src/App.js I made a codesandbox and it's working fine. maybe I just check all my dependencies maybe I just miss something.

Comment: From your root project directory you can check the installed version of react with `npm list react`. Or you may just need to re-run `npm install` to install all the project's dependencies, and then restart any development servers, i.e. `npm start`.